# How can I create a single x axis label and y axis label for mutiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code:

```
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.suptitle('Finding the roots of the equation: z^4 - 1 = 0')
ticks = [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

pyplot.subplot(221)
pyplot.imshow(roots, extent=(x0, x1, y0, y1))
pyplot.xticks(ticks)
pyplot.yticks(ticks)

pyplot.subplot(222)
pyplot.imshow(iterations, extent=(x0, x1, y0, y1))
pyplot.colorbar(orientation='vertical')
pyplot.xticks(ticks)
pyplot.yticks(ticks)

pyplot.subplot(223)
pyplot.imshow(roots_zoom, extent=(x2, x3, y2, y3))

pyplot.subplot(224)
pyplot.imshow(iterations_zoom, extent=(x2, x3, y2, y3))
pyplot.colorbar(orientation='vertical')

pyplot.show()
```

I'm plotting four arrays of numbers as images in a 2x2 figure of subplots. I want the same x label and y label for each. How do I create one x label that is centered below the two bottom plots and one y label that is centered to the left of the left two plots?

Also, how do I change the specified tick marks to floats? I've created them as [-2.0 ... 2.0] but they are shown in the figure as -2, -1, 0 etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should ask one question per thread.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with [`Figure.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.text)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.text(.5, .1, 'xlabel', ha='center')
fig.text(.1, .5, 'ylabel', ha='center', rotation='vertical')
```

You will need to tweak the location of the text to put it exactly where you want.

You will want to look into [`Formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting)s to control how your tick labels are displayed.  You can get one decimal place floats with

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
```